# How can I sort this list according to the crescent order of the element[0] of the tuples?

Tags: python, python-2.7, sorting, tuples

[The image of the list sorted with sort()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i1PK4.png)

I'd like something like this

[(**0**, 'dunno'), (**1**, 'dunno'), (**2**, 'dunno'), (**3**, 'dunno'), (**4**, 'dunno'), (**5**, 'n'), (**6**, 'dunno'), ...]

I already tried the

```
sorted(list_of_tuples, key=lambda x: x[0])
```

Comment: So why is that not working?

Comment: I updated the details. The image shows the list sorted with sort(). It doesn't give me the wanted result.

Answer (score 1):

`sorted()` doesn't sort the list, it returns a sorted list. If you want to sort in-place then use the `sort()` method instead.

Answer (score -1):

A part of the solution is here. The problem is that now at the beginning there is one string that I want to be at the end of the list.

```
for line in list_of_tuples:
    line=line.sort(reverse=False)
```

Comment: You will be overwriting _line_ over and over again

Comment: And _reverse=False_ is default value

Comment: What's the concern related to "You will be overwriting line over and over again"?